# Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a web map using leaflet. It is my first time in this. So, I follow a tutorial from leaflet. However, when I try to open a geojson file in my page, an error occurs:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///...../page/map.geojson' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https."

I have windows 10. 
I search this error. However I do not understand the tips. I have afraid to do something wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Looks like the geojson file is on your local computer and the page was loaded from a server. This form of cross-origin access isn't allowed. Copy the geojson onto the server and use the same URL scheme that your page loads with (http? https?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am working in my computer, not a server. I create a folder and I am developing the web map (in HTML file) in my computer. Also with the geojson file.

Comment: I found the answer. I follow this instructions: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/install-and-setup-a-website-in-iis-on-windows-10/. Then the geojson file cannot had the extension .geojson but .js and it works. Thank you a lot anyway.